# 'POST 400 bad request' error when updating parse.com table

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am getting a 'POST 400 bad request' error when trying to update a table on parse.com using JS SDK.

```
var Gallery = Parse.Object.extend("Gallery");
var gallery = new Gallery();
var activeArtworks = 0;
gallery.save(null, {
    success: function(gallery) {
          gallery.set("activeArtworks", activeArtworks);
          gallery.save();
    }
});
```

Please help!

I can't see how this is any different to the sample code provided by parse [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide/#objects-updating)

Comment: Can you look in the chrome debugger at the actual http request that's returning 400 and include it in your question?

Comment: Sure can @bklimt. Here it is: POST https://api.parse.com/1/classes/galleries/cn5t2w81qN 400 (Bad Request) parse-1.0.0.min.js:1
b._ajax parse-1.0.0.min.js:1
b._request parse-1.0.0.min.js:1
c.extend.save parse-1.0.0.min.js:1
gallery.save.success fgcViewartwork.js:211
c.extend.save.p.success parse-1.0.0.min.js:1
b._ajax.g.onreadystatechange

Comment: Ignore the fact that "/galleries/" in the API request and the Gallery name in my code doesn't match here. I have fixed that a while ago - that's not the problem here

Comment: i have the same issue.  400 (Bad Request)   Some times it works, some times it fails.

Comment: Pardon me if this is stupid, but is the gallery object's parameters initialized before the request? Maybe you should put something like gallery.set("activeArtworks", 0); before the save method.

Comment: I also think @HugoRocha is right. You are trying to create/update a gallery with nothing actually changed.

Answer (score 4):

The sample code you reference creates all of its parameters before setting up the save() method. This is the step you're missing; you need to create the activeArtworks parameter on your gallery instance. Your update is failing because you're trying to update a property that was never created.

I would expect this code to work, though I didn't test it because parse.com requires you to set up an account to run any code, which is silly, and I didn't feel like creating one:

```
var Gallery = Parse.Object.extend("Gallery");
var gallery = new Gallery();
var activeArtworks = 0;
gallery.activeArtworks = []; // or some more appropriate default if you have one.
gallery.save(null, {
    success: function(gallery) {
        gallery.set("activeArtworks", activeArtworks);
        gallery.save();
    }
});
```

It might also be worth checking if there's any info in the headers of the 400 error (the debug console in your browser will show these in its Network tab). I would expect Parse to give you some sort of information to help you debug issues, and that's the only place it would fit for an HTTP error.

Answer (score 0):

If you had use user.logIn(callback) function with Parse JS, maybe your session invalid. Please check your callback function error code, if `error.code==209` (invalid session token), use `Parse.User.logOut()` and re-login again.

Like this:

```
if (error.code == 209) {    
    Parse.User.logOut();
    user.logIn(loginCallback);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and it was resolved after realising that the data type that I was posting was different to that specified in the columns that I had created. 
In my case, I was trying to save an object when I had specified an array when creating the column in the class.